# How to fix the baseurl of plone?

Tags: url, plone, multilingual, linguaplone

I create the multi language website with linguaplone.
Now I should fix the baseurl to `.../en` or `...../de` for two versions.

what should I do?

Comment: Normally, the base URL takes care of itself. What actual problems do you see?

Comment: I have fix it , modify the template like this:<base tal:attributes="href string:$portal_url/$lang/" />

But how to tell the system not to convert relative link to absolute one  in richtext field ? god, it is hard code?

Comment: That is *not* a fix, you've now broken the native `<base />` tag support of Plone. *Don't* do that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: why does plone replace the internal link in richtext with absolute link? I need relative url in content type created by dexterity

Answer (score 0):

I have really no idea what you are exactly asking and why.

But you are probably want to set navigation base URL using LinguaPlone language folders feature

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.LinguaPlone/4.1.2#installation

See @@language-setup-folders